# React calling callback function infinity

Tags: reactjs, callback

I am new to React. I am facing an issue of infinite call of callback function.

I have component A having function handleAssignUser().

```
handleAssignUser = (id) =>{
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({user_id:id});
  }
```

I am passing this function to Component B as callback.

```
<AssignTaskUserList usersLists={this.state.usersLists} callBack={()=>this.handleAssignUser} />
```

On Component B. I have to call this function inside componentWillReceiveProps() and on selection of user.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.funUserAssignTo(loginUser);
}

<button key={user._id} className="dropdown-item" type="button" onClick={(e)=>this.funUserAssignTo(user)}><span>{user.name}</span></button>


funUserAssignTo(user = ""){
    var self = this;
    if(General.notEmpty(user)){
      this.setState({
        selectedUser: user
      },() => {self.props.callBack(user._id)});
    }
  }
```

This is calling callback function infinite. Please suggest me where I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`callBack={()=>this.handleAssignUser}` is not correct
this equal to

```
() => {
  this.handleAssignUser; // not running
}
```

use `callBack={this.handleAssignUser}` instead

Comment: I tried it already, its not work. The function call infinite.

Comment: Is your `self.props.callBack` changing the props for componentB? when the props updated, it will call componentWillReceiveProps again, try use `if (this.props.sth !== nextProps.sth)` to check whether your target props is updated or not, before calling `this.funUserAssignTo` in `componentWillReceiveProps`